# C++ output elements of a vector not expected

Tags: c++, ranged-loops

I'm practicing vector and ranged for loop, my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int size,element;
    cout<<"enter vector size: ";
    cin>>size;
    vector<int>v(size);
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        cout<<i<<"\t";
        cin>>element;
        v.push_back(element);
    }
    for(int p : v) cout<<p<<" ";
}
```

I entered 3 then 1, 2, 3 but the output is "0 0 0 1 2 3". Could you please explain me where the 0s are from? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vector<int>v(size);
```

This creates a vector of having size equal to size variable. Now if you do push_back it will create a new vector and with size+1 and add the element to it.
Instead inside for loop do `cin>>v[i];`

Answer (score 0):

`vector<int>v(size);` creates a vector of `size` zero-initialised elements (in your case 3).  `push_back` then adds new elements to the end of this vector, which explains the results you get.

You can reserve space for elements in the vector with `reserve`.  This speeds things up somewhat if you know in advance how many elements you will be adding.

Comment: As an addendum, you may want to look up the `reserve` method of `vector`.  For some applications it makes sense to make a default (zero) sized vector, and then call `reserve` to get the memory size you want (while vector size doesn't change), and then add your values in.

Comment: We don't use ranged loop to cin element of a vector right? Because I only see examples with cout using ranged loop (for(int u : v) cin>>v[u]; doesn't work)

Comment: It would be OK if you don't change the size of the vector inside the loop.

Comment: Thank you very much!